# Owl carousel Как скрывать стрелочки навигации при отсутствии цикла

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

Как в Owl carousel скрывать стрелочки следующего/предыдущего слайда при отсутствии бесконечного цикла ?

Приведу пример картинками [image: Первая позиция]
Первая позиция.
[image: Вторая позиция]

После нажатия стрелки Вперед

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Последняя позиция, больше слайдов нету.

У некоторых слайдеров такое задано по умолчанию, если возможность подкючить данный эффект тут ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var owl = $("#owl-example");
  owl.owlCarousel({
      nav: true,  
  }); 
});
```

```css
.owl-next.disabled, .owl-prev.disabled  {
  display: none !important; /*Скрыть неактивную кнопку*/
}


/*css для примера*/
.owl-nav {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.owl-nav div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #8BC34A;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin:1px;
}
/*css для примера*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div id="owl-example"  class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
 <div class="item"><img src="http://www.fepsearchgroup.com/demos/assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://www.fepsearchgroup.com/demos/assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://www.fepsearchgroup.com/demos/assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://www.fepsearchgroup.com/demos/assets//owl4.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
  <div class="item"><img src="http://www.fepsearchgroup.com/demos/assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

У owlCarousel, при выключенном `loop`, элементы навигации, при дослайде до конца, получают класс `.disabled`. Пропишите селектор с `display: none;`.